# Prolog Summing Fields in a Database

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog and I understand how to calculate the sum of a list but I can't figure out how to compute the sum of the fields of a database.

```
Sample database:

tastiness(bacon,100,200,300,400,500).
tastiness(lettuce,3,5,6,7,12).

Sample output
(bacon,1500).
(lettuce,33).
```

Comment: What kind of Prolog system are you using? This isn't Prolog syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to sum the values of a list in standard Prolog:

```
sumlist([], 0).
sumlist([X|Xs], Sum) :-
    sumlist(Xs, SumTail),
    Sum is X + SumTail.
```

If you have something like

```
bacon(100).
bacon(200).
bacon(300).
bacon(400).
bacon(500).
```

you could then use the [`findall`](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node96.html) predicate. The `findall` predicate works as follows: If you want `Z = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]` (the list of all bacon numbers) you write `findall(X, bacon(X), Z)`.

Here's how to sum all bacon numbers:

```
| ?- findall(X, bacon(X), AllBacon), sumlist(AllBacon, SumBacon).

AllBacon = [100,200,300,400,500]
SumBacon = 1500

yes
```

Comment: The database is just a list of facts (I fixed the formatting). Thanks but I don't know how to traverse the variables in each predicate.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to put together a list of numbers across a predicate? ie. bacon(100, 200, 300, 400, 500). => [100,200, 300, 400, 500].

Comment: you should probably do `bacon([100, 200, 300, 400, 500]).` And then, if you need the list of all bacon numbers, you do `bacon(BaconNumbers)`. After that `BaconNumbers` will be bound to the list.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, the sum computation proposed by @aioobe is not optimal because on a very large list, you will run out of call stack memory.

A particular technique is to put the recursive call of the predicate as the last element of your predicate. This way, all preceding things being already computed, Prolog can flush the current context of the predicate while making the recursive call. On a list with 1M elements, that means than you will run with 1 context being kept instead of up to one million.

While it may not seem important to you for this particular exercise, the tail call optimization is what makes recursion as powerful as iteration, if you take space consumption into consideration. It's worth learning!

Here is a version on which [Tail Call Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is performable:

```
sumlist(List, Result) :-
    sumlist(List, 0, Result).

sumlist([], Acc, Acc).
sumlist([Item|List], Acc, Result) :-
    NewAcc is Acc + Item.
    sumlist(List, NewAcc, Result).
```

It makes use of an idiom you will encounter a lot in declarative programming: an accumulator (here named `Acc`). Its purpose is to hold the resulting value "up until now" during the recursion.